# Set GRUB `elevator=deadline` scheduling to a single device

Tags: linux, grub2, hard-disk, scheduling

I'd like to set my secondary drive to `deadline`. Is it possible to do it via GRUB, but leaving the primary drive as `cfq`?

A script after booting would suffice in my case, but I'm interested in the GRUB alternative.